# Скрипт опросника через switch

Tags: javascript

Код используется для теста-опросника, состоящего из 10 вопросов и 3 вариантов ответов в каждом (a, b и с). Результат должен выдаваться в зависимости от выбранных букв. Например если ответов "а" = 6, то один текст, если ответов "b" = 10, то другой текст, если ответов "с"= 6 то третий текст, и если ответов a, b и с каждого меньше 4, то четвертый текст. Скрипт срабатывает только для варианта "а", а других будто бы и нет вообще. 
Что здесь неверно?

```
            $(function(){

            $('.questionForm input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e){
                var answer_a=0;
                var answer_b=0;
                var answer_c=0;
                for(i=0;i<$('.group').length;i++){
                $('.group').eq(i).each(function(id, elem){
                if($(elem).find('input:checked').length!=0){

            if($(elem).find('input:checked').attr('value')=="a"){
                                answer_a++;
                            }
            if($(elem).find('input:checked').attr('value')=="b"){
                                answer_b++;
                            }
            if($(elem).find('input:checked').attr('value')=="c"){
                                answer_c++;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
      var general_a = (answer_a/$('.group').length)*10;
      var general_b = (answer_b/$('.group').length)*10;
      var general_c = (answer_c/$('.group').length)*10;
      var greeting;
      if (general_a == 4) {
          greeting = "Text-4!";
      } else if (general_b == 4 ) {
          greeting = "Text-4!";
      } else if (general_c == 4 ) {
          greeting = "Text-4!";
      } else if (general_a == 6 ) {
          greeting = "Text-1!";
      } else if (general_b == 10 ) {
          greeting = "Text-2!";          
      } else if (general_c == 6 ) {
          greeting = "Text-3!";          
      }                 
      else {
          greeting = "Anything";
      }
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = greeting;
      return false;
            })
        })
```

Comment: "Что здесь неверно?" - *(перевожу)* - Вам тут все равно делать нечего. Вот код. Разметку и все остальное придумайте сами. Кроме того, так как код работает неправильно, догадайтесь, что он должен делать. Только, чтобы это было правильно! Ну, и ответ мне напишите.

Comment: Что показывают консоль логи a, b, c соответственно?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что работают только первые два?

Comment: Чтобы сработали третий и далее должно выполнятся неравенство `4 < general_a < 6`. Оно выполняется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Все действия, описанные в моем комментарии к вопросу, я проделал в голове. В сухом остатке:*

`switch` так не работает. Вам нужен `if { ... } else if { ... }`.

Comment: Код используется для теста-опросника, состоящего из 10 вопросов и 3 вариантов ответов в каждом (a, b и с). Результат должен выдаваться в зависимости от выбранных букв. Например если ответов "а" = 6, то один текст, если ответов "b" = 10,  то другой текст, если ответов "с"= 6 то третий текст, и если ответов a, b и с каждого меньше 4, то четвертый текст. Скрипт срабатывает только для варианта "а", а других будто бы и нет вообще.

Comment: @Natalia Вам понятна последняя строчка в ответе?

Comment: понятна, только с if { ... } else if { ... } теперь тоже не совсем получается, в нужном блоке проскакивает самый первый вариант текста и исчезает.

Comment: @Natalia Хм, теперь Вы не отменяете отправку формы на сервер, так как убрали `return false;`. Пожалуйста, будьте внимательнее.

Comment: Спасибо, добавила return false, но выводиться только один первый вариант, при любом выборе ответов.

Comment: @Natalia замените `=` (присваивание) на `==` (сравнение) в условиях Ваших `if (...)`/`else if (...)`

Comment: Спасибо, огромное! Заработало! ))

Comment: @Natalia :) На здоровье. Успехов! Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".

Answer (score 0):

На ванильном яваскрипте if { ... } else if { ... }. Оператор switch для случаев чисел или существительных например switch в случае (картошка) сделать то-то и то-то. А у вас уравнение больше и меньше, поэтому используйте if else структуру, пожалуйста.
ЗЫ и switch Это не оператор.

Answer (score 0):

Если очень нужен свитч, то можно так

```
 switch (true){
    case (general_a === 6):
        greeting = "text-1!";
    break;
    case (general_a <== 4 || general_b <== 4 || general_c <== 4):
        greeting = "text-4!";
    break;
        case (general_b === 10):
    greeting = "text-2!";
    break;
        case (general_c === 6):
    greeting = "text-3!";
    break;
    default:
        greeting = "Anything";
    }
```

и у вас ошибка в конструкции if() условия надо писать через двойные или тройные === >== <== у вас везде просто = в итоге условия не срабатывают и он просто присваивает константу, поэтому у вас ничего не работает

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду знать) Там исправила, уже все работает.